# Problem with \leq displaying as \leqslant

Tags: symbols

I assume it has something to do with my custom macro package, but I'm not really sure. I've just noticed that all of my \leq display as \leqslant the only thing that I could think would effect it is the beginning of my macro.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{macro}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,fancyhdr,mathabx}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=.75 in,bottom=.75 in, left=.75 in, right= .75 in]{geometry}
```

But this all seems pretty harmless. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, coding in emacs, compiling by pdflatex (pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2) through auctex. I'll be happy to provide any more information, or the rest of my macro document if it would help. My headings are pretty generic:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{macro}
\author{}
\title{Abstract Algebra Homework 5}\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this regard `mathabx` is not “harmless” as its purpose is to [provide and changes lots of symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathabx/mathtest.pdf). In particular, it changes the `\le` symbol (see page 6 of the manual). It also provides `\varleq`, which looks closer to the Computer Modern `\le`.

Comment: Okay, I had added mathabx for \bigtimes. I'll see if my professors complain about the slanted leq.

Comment: @liberalkid to only include the big operators you can include `mathabx` with the `mathx` option. If that does not work for you (because you want other symbols as well), you can do always redefine `\leq` as `\varleq` (`\renewcommand\leq\varleq`).

Answer (score 4):

Caramdir provided a very good TeXnical answer; let me give a short aesthetical one: I'd just be happy and stick with the `\leqslant` version since it looks much better, in my opinion. This is of course personal taste, but I like that it's closer to what I do in handwriting.

Answer (score 2):

As a note to whoever might find it useful, the Euler math (package `euler` or `eulervm`) also slants the less-than-equal or greater-than-equal symbols. This is used e.g. in `classicthesis` which I am using. I just spent a long time trying to figure it out as I haven't included `mathabx` in my code. Duh ...

If you still like to use your font (e.g. the above-mentioned `euler`) but want the classic less-equal symbol, you can pull it out, by putting this in your preamble:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% taken from mathabx.sty. Version: May 18, 2005.
% Author: Anthony PHAN.
% matches the ``mathabx'' family.
% LaTeX input/style file
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleq}{3}{matha}{"A8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vargeq}{3}{matha}{"A9}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And maybe also make it used:

```
\renewcommand{\leq}{\varleq}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\vargeq}
```

Likely, there are easier ways. Maybe it would be a better idea to get it out of the default font.