# How do I pass options to a package?

Tags: packages, package-options

I apologize if this is a neophyte or duplicate question because I was unable to find it.

A comment on the question [Problem with \leq displaying as \leqslant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/problem-with-leq-displaying-as-leqslant), mentions that "you can include mathabx with the mathx option".

How exactly does one pass the mathx option to the mathabx package, or more generally pass options to LaTeX packages?

In addition to Google, I have also experimented with each of the following, all of which resulted in error messages.

```
\usepackage{mathabx}{mathx}
\usepackage{mathabx}[mathx]
\usepackage[mathx]{mathabx}
```

Comment: The third way is the correct way, so if you're getting an error you need to show us more detail of what you did. Ideally a complete minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: I think this question should be closed. It appears that I mistook an error that was generated BECAUSE the option was correctly passed for an error with the package.

Comment: You can just delete it, I think, if you like.

Comment: If you misunderstood an error message it is likely someone else _may_ in the future as well. It would be helpful if you expanded the question to include the exact message that you thought was an error and perhaps provided a self answer.  That way if someone else encounters the same issue they will hopefully find this answer and be able to remedy the situation.

Comment: As far as I know, I can only "vote to delete" rather than deleting outright. 
@PeterGrill I will take your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the suggestion in the comment, I wanted to clarify that the last option I tried was the correct option. The correct way is thus:

```
\usepackage[mathx]{mathabx}
```

It turned out a different part of my source depended on the other symbols in the package `mathabx`.

I was not expecting an error on a different line, so I assumed that it was something wrong with the package parameter passing.